# Copy and paste with C#

Tags: c#

I know this is asked many times before but it s not what i look for, to make copy paste in c# we use;

```
//Copy
Clipboard.SetDataObject("String to copy"); 

//Paste
IDataObject iData = Clipboard.GetDataObject();
```

I only want to use copy, after using:

```
Clipboard.SetDataObject("String to copy");
```

when i close the program, then when i right click and paste on a txt file nothing happens!

So Clipboard class seems doesnt help, so i need another solution.

Comment: "Right click and paste on a txt file". Could you elaborate on what you mean by that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Clipboard.SetDataObject("String to copy", true);
```

That boolean value at the end specifies whether the string should remain in the clipboard after the application closes, and is set to false as default.

Answer (score 3):

You want to use second overload of [SetDataObject(object, bool)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cs5ebdfz.aspx).

When `bool` is set to `true`, data will remain after application is closed.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to use `Clipboard.SetText(your_String)`?
This works for me.